# Can't start Glassfish 3.1.2.2 on Eclipse Juno

Tags: java, eclipse, deployment, glassfish

I updated to Eclipse Juno, and since then, it seems that I can't start or debug Glassfish when I could do it perfectly before. When starting the server I get this console output...

```
INFO: Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 (build 5)
INFO: Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.50 started in: 1978ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:7676]
INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.50 started in: 2031ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:3700]
INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.50 started in: 2165ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:8080]
INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.50 started in: 2071ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:4848]
INFO: Grizzly Framework 1.9.50 started in: 2077ms - bound to [0.0.0.0:8181]
INFO: SEC1002: Security Manager is OFF.
SEVERE: Exception while deploying the app [LuxorAutorizacionesBackEnd]
```

I can't deploy on eclipse, but when I export the project to a WAR file and put it on the autodeploy folder of the glassfish server, and start it on command prompt it starts perfectly fine.

I'm on Windows 7 x64, using Glassfish OpenSource 3.1.2.2 with Eclipse Juno

Answer (score 0):

You have to change jreX.X to appropriate jdkX.X(where is X.X some number of version jre or jdk). I find on the web that glassfish now need jdk like default environment.

You have to go in eclipse to the widow>Installed JREs and click on add button to setup jdk instead jre. And after this you have to go in properties of project and click on java build path end mark glassfish system libraries. It is news of the glassFish in new version.